# How does Jane know that Harley saw her & Jake at the hotel?

Tags: plot-explanation, its-complicated

In *[It's Complicated](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1230414/)*, Jane privately asks Harley about what he saw at the hotel:

> Jane: What did you see and what do you know?
>
> Harley: Nothing. Really.
>
> Jane: Harley
>
> Harley: Okay, he checked in, then you arrived. Then you met at the
>   elevator, possible kiss there.Then the doctor went up and the doctor
>   came down. Then there was a thumbs-up, but that's it.I have no idea
>   what happened in between.
>
> Jane: Have you told Lauren?
>
> Harley: No, and I won't.

Harley is Lauren's fiance, Jane & Jake divorced so many years back. Lauren is Jake and Jane's daughter. Harley saw Jane & Jake meeting at hotel.
this is what Jane asks him in this dialogue.

**How did Jane know that Harley saw her & Jake at hotel?**

Comment: I believe that Lauren was telling Jane that her and Harley were at the same hotel that day with their wedding planner and Jane found out that way, but I will have to check.  Harley and Lauren aren't married, btw.  They are in the midst of planning their wedding in the movie :)

Comment: What i am asking is totally **different** I think .

Comment: You want to know how Jane knows, right?  There is a conversation that Lauren has where she tells everyone in the room that her and Harley were at that same hotel at that same time with their wedding planner.  Jane gets a shocked look on her face...unless you're asking something else.

Answer (score -1):

It's just something she gets from the conversation and the way Harley acts.

The [**screenplay**](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/It's-Complicated.html) has more context...

> **LAUREN** :-- Oh, Mom, I keep forgetting to tell you about our meeting at The
>    Stanhope. We went there for lunch two days ago and met with their Wedding Specialist....I think that could be the place, Mom.... **
>
> **JANE** : Two days ago you went to The Stanhope...for lunch?
>
> **HARLEY** : Yes and guess what? **We saw nothing.**
>
> **Jane and Harley connect.** He immediately looks away.

Basically, what he says and the way he says it lead Jane to believe that he knows **something** even if he initially denies it. She's not sure *how much* or what *exactly* he saw or knows and so she asks him..

> Okay...What did you see and what do you know?